# Dicord.net offline users always return null when trying to ban

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

i'm making a discord bot in c# using Discord.net.
Now, i'm trying to ban an user that's offline. But it seems to return null.
If the person is online it doesn't

```
(channel.Guild.GetUser(message.MentionedUsers.First().Id)
```

is how i get the user for the null check.

```
(user.Guild.AddBanAsync(user, 1, messageArray[2]).IsCompleted)
```

is how i ban

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch the user by calling `GetUser` if you already have the user in mentioned users collection?

Answer (score 0):

Try `user.BanAsync()`. With this you can ban a user.

If this doesn't work try `user.Guild.AddBanAsync(user.Is)`. With this you can ban a user with his id.